# Getting "Contents hidden" as replacement in custom layout public notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like to set the italic "Contents hidden" message for a public notification manually.
Android seem to set "Contents hidden" automatically if only a `VISIBILITY_PRIVATE` notification without a public counterpart is presented.
Here, the `setContent`-parts are automatically replaced.
For an example from K9mail see screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYYgS.png).

However, I would like to use a custom layout for the public notification while letting the notification look similar (i.e., "Contents hidden").
It is a notification for a music player, which should provide buttons for pause and play next songs.

So, how can I either

1. access the (localized) value for "Contents hidden" that Android is actually using (not implementing it manually) or
2. tell Android to replace all "setContent"-parts automatically as if I would not provide a public notification.

Any suggestions?

For the sake of completeness - the issue is related with this pull request: https://github.com/gateship-one/odyssey/pull/120

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple just use:

```
  String foo = mContext.getString(android.content.res.Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("notification_hidden_text", "string", "android"));
```